# Unable to detect undefined names

Tags: pyqt4, qt-designer

New to QtDesigner and PyQt and trying to get my first simple application going. (The user enters anywhere from one to three values in LineEdits and the sum is put in a fourth LineEdit). I created the GUI (simpleAdder1.py) with Qt Designer and then wrote the following code (callsimpleAdder1.pyw). Unfortunately it's not running and code analysis suggests a problem at the 'from simpleAdder1 import *' line. The problem is ...."from simpleAdder1 import * ,used, unable to detect undefined names'

I originally thought it was a path problem. But simpleAdder1.py is in the same directory as callsimpleadder1.pyw. I also copied simpleAdder1 into one of the paths that Python checks and that didn't help.

Where am I going wrong ? What names are undefined ? How do I fix this ?

```
import sys
from simpleAdder1 import *

class MyForm(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui=Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)        

    def on_v1Input_textChanged(self):
        self.ui.calcResult()        

    def on_v2Input_textChanged(self):
        self.ui.calcResult()   

    def on_v3Input_textChanged(self):
        self.ui.calcResult()   

    def calcResult(self):
        if len(self.ui.v1Input.txt())!=0:
            a=float(self.ui.v1Input.txt())
        else:
            a=0
        if len(self.ui.v2Input.txt())!=0:
            b=float(self.ui.v2Input.txt())
        else:
            b=0
        if len(self.ui.v3Input.txt())!=0:
            c=float(self.ui.v1Input.txt())
        else:
            c=0
        sum=a+b+c
        self.ui.calc_result.setText(+str(sum))       

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp=MyForm()
    myapp.show
    app.exec_()
```

The code for the GUI (simpleAdder1) is as follows:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(673, 565)
        self.v1Input = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.v1Input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 70, 71, 20))
        self.v1Input.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("v1Input"))
        self.v2Input = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.v2Input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 70, 71, 20))
        self.v2Input.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("v2Input"))
        self.v3Input = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.v3Input.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 70, 71, 20))
        self.v3Input.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("v3Input"))
        self.calc_result = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.calc_result.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 70, 113, 20))
        self.calc_result.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("calc_result"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 50, 46, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 50, 46, 13))
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 50, 46, 13))
        self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
        self.label_4 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(450, 50, 46, 13))
        self.label_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_4"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 230, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.v1Input.clear)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.v2Input.clear)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.v3Input.clear)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

        #QtCore.QObject.connect(self.v1Input,QtCore.SIGNAL("textChanged"),self.calcResult)
        #QtCore.QObject.connect(self.v2Input,QtCore.SIGNAL("textChanged"),self.calcResult)
        #QtCore.QObject.connect(self.v3Input,QtCore.SIGNAL("textChanged"),self.calcResult)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Val 1", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Val 2", None))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Val 3", None))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Result", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Clear Inputs", None))
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you question. Your question is "Why have error undefined name in Ui_Dialog ?" or not ? Please explain, thanks.

Comment: When I run callsimpleadder1, nothing happens. When I look at the code for callsimpleadder1, there is a code analysis comment (warning or error, im not sure) that says "from simpleAdder1 import * ,used, unable to detect undefined names". So the second statement in callsimpleadder1 (from simpleAdder1 import *0 seems to be a problem.

So my questions are why won't callsimpleadder1 run ? And what is the problem whith my second statement in callsimpleadder1 ?

Comment: OK, I think I (maybe) understand your problem. Please read my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I (maybe) understand your problem.

```
Unfortunately it's not running and code analysis suggests a problem at the 'from simpleAdder1 import *' line. The problem is ...."from simpleAdder1 import * ,used, unable to detect undefined names'
```

I see your code the problem widget can't show isn't this error I think error this your path file.
But, I use PyDev 2.8.2 on Eclipse Kepler Service Release 1, It have (little) warning unused import like this,

```
Unused in wild import: QtCore
Found at: simpleAdder1
```

Then, I suggest to use "used import" only, like this;

```
from simpleAdder1 import Ui_Dialog, QtGui
```

---

And what is going wrong your GUI ? It's because this line in **main**;

```
myapp.show
```

To solve problem, please "Call function" (In old isn't call function anything) like this;

```
myapp.show()
```

---

Regards,

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. It worked! The myapp.show without the () was my silly mistake. But I have one question. Why does "from simpleAdder1 import Ui_Dialog, QtGui" work but 'from simpleAdder1 import *' not work ?

Comment: I think this log (unable to detect undefined names), It just warning show to programmer if use PyFlakes, that said "I can't detect undefined names & import". It not error just warning (I think). You can avoid it or avoid import all and use "used import" only. Ref: http://flake8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/warnings.html

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Just a warning. When I fixed a few other problems with the code that I had, it ran with the warning. My mistake was that I was not getting any other errors at the console so I assumed the 'can't detect undefined names' was the problem.

Comment: That great, you can continue your project. ;)